# Passing array php into json gives undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I want to pass a JSON from php to js.

This is my php file :

```
 public function upload() {
    $record = 0;
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $config['upload_path'] = "./assets/uploads";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file")) {
            echo "File cannot be uploaded";
        } else {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            $csv = $upload_data['full_path'];
            $name_csv = $upload_data['file_name'];
            $tryOne = array();

            if (file_exists($csv)) {
                $file = fopen($csv, 'r'); // r flag is for readonly mode

                while (( $line = fgetcsv($file) ) !== false) { // if line exists
                    $tryOne[] = $line; // add to array
                }

                fclose($file);
            }

            echo json_encode(array(
                "nama_csv" => $name_csv,
                "path" => $csv,
                "isi" => $tryOne
            ));
        }
    } elseif ($this->input->post('file_to_remove')) {
        $file_to_remove = $this->input->post('file_to_remove');
        unlink("./assets/uploads/" . $file_to_remove);
    } else {
        $this->listFiles();
    }
}
```

Please see in mv json. I debug it : `print_r($tryOne);`

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => NO
        [1] => COLUMN1
        [2] => COLUMN2
        [3] => COLUMN3
        [4] => COLUMN4
        [5] => COLUMN5
        [6] => COLUMN6
        [7] => COLUMN7
        [8] => COLUMN8
        [9] => COULMN9
        [10] => COLUMN10
        [11] => COLUMN11
        [12] => COLUMN12
        [13] => COLUMN13
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => NYK FUJI                      
        [2] => AJU150708 
        [3] =>                     
        [4] => 6C7132    
        [5] => 977NEF    
        [6] => JKT-P.T.IRON WORKS            
        [7] => 977NEF    
        [8] => KCH8ATDM  
        [9] => 17.9
        [10] => 1690
        [11] => 2150
        [12] => 6C7132-1690         
        [13] => 175
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => NYK FUJI                      
        [2] => AJU150708 
        [3] =>                     
        [4] => 6C7132    
        [5] => 977NEF    
        [6] => JKT-P.T.IRON WORKS            
        [7] => 977NEF    
        [8] => KCH8ATDM  
        [9] => 17.9
        [10] => 1700
        [11] => 2138
        [12] => 6C7132-1700         
        [13] => 176
    )

)
```

Everything looks fine. But in ajax success :

```
 success: function (response) {
                    moment.locale("id");
                    for (i = 0; i <= response.isi.length; i++) {
                        for (j = 0; j <= response.isi[i].length; j++) {
                            $('#table-review').find('tbody').append("<tr>" +
                                    "<td>" + response.isi[i][j] + "</td>" +
                                    "</tr>");
                        }
                    }
                    $("#btnSave").attr("onclick", "save('" + response.path + "', '" + response.nama_csv + "')");

                    $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
                    $('.modal-title').text('Review Data Hasil Upload Dari CSV Pusat'); // Set Title to Bootstrap modal title


                    reload_table();
                    listFilesOnServer();
                },
```

gives me : **TypeError: response.isi[i] is undefined**

I want to display this array into a table in modal bootstrap, so i debug it again to see if response.isi is exist : `console.log(response.isi)`

```
 [["NO", "COLUMN1", "COLUMN2", 11 more...]
```

I little confused, why in php array and js array looks like different, 
in php is separated into element, but in js is separated by comma.

**UPDATE**

Based suggestion below, I got a callback like this :

```
 Object { 0="NO",  1="COLUMN1",  2="COLUMN2",  more...}
 Object { 0="1",  1="NYK FUJI",  2="AJU150708 ",  more...}
 Object { 0="2",  1="NYK FUJI",  2="AJU150708 ",  more...}
```

So, I use for looping like this :

```
 index = 1;
  $.each(response.isi, function (i, item) {
  $('#table-review').find('tbody').append("<tr>" +
      "<td>" + index + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + item.i + "</td>" +
      "</tr>");
    index++;
    console.log(item);
  });
```

it gives me :

```
+---+-----------+
| 1 | undefined |
| 2 | undefined |
| 3 | undefined |
+---+-----------+
```

Please advise.

Comment: alright, i am not sure if you are getting the correct output. but if your $tryone array is not associative array, then you do not need to pass second parameter JSON_FORCE_OBJECT and use array like $.each(response.isi, function(i, item) as shown in the answer by @Óscar Gómez Alcañiz below.

Answer (score 0):

in php encode it like this

```
echo json_encode(array(
            "nama_csv" => $name_csv,
            "path" => $csv,
            "isi" => $tryOne
        ), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

In ajax you have to parse it. As you seem to be using jquery then you can do like this

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

and then you get array. Use that like `data.isi` or `data['isi']`. Not sure which one of this will work according to your array type.

Answer (score 0):

For the error after your update:

You are accessing the wrong index in your loop. See the corrected code:

```
var index = 1;
$.each(response.isi, function (i, item) {
$('#table-review').find('tbody').append("<tr>" +
    "<td>" + index + "</td>" +
    //"<td>" + item.i + "</td>" + // wrong: i doesn't exist as a property of item
    "<td>" + item[i] + "</td>" + // right: item array at index i will work
    "</tr>");
  index++;
  console.log(item);
});
```