# For looping in json to create a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is continues form : [Passing array php into json gives undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092368/passing-array-php-into-json-gives-undefined)
. So I have a json named response.isi based success ajax like this :

```
{
"0": {
    "0": "NO",
    "1": "COLUMN1",
    "2": "COLUMN2",
    "3": "COLUMN3",
    "4": "COLUMN4",
    "5": "COLUMN5",
    "6": "COLUMN6",
    "7": "COLUMN7",
    "8": "COLUMN8",
    "9": "COULMN9",
    "10": "COLUMN10",
    "11": "COLUMN11",
    "12": "COLUMN12",
    "13": "COLUMN13"
},
"1": {
    "0": "1",
    "1": "NYK FUJI ",
    "2": "AJU150708 ",
    "3": " ",
    "4": "6C7132 ",
    "5": "977NEF ",
    "6": "JKT-P.T.IRON WORKS ",
    "7": "977NEF ",
    "8": "KCH8ATDM ",
    "9": "17.9",
    "10": "1690",
    "11": "2150",
    "12": "6C7132-1690 ",
    "13": "175"
},
"2": {
    "0": "2",
    "1": "NYK FUJI ",
    "2": "AJU150708 ",
    "3": " ",
    "4": "6C7132 ",
    "5": "977NEF ",
    "6": "JKT-P.T.IRON WORKS ",
    "7": "977NEF ",
    "8": "KCH8ATDM ",
    "9": "17.9",
    "10": "1700",
    "11": "2138",
    "12": "6C7132-1700 ",
    "13": "176"
  }
}
```

it looks charm. Now , I confused to access them to interprated into html table. I use jquery like this:

```
 $.each(response.isi, function (i, item) {
  $('#table-review').find('tbody').append("<tr>" +
    "<td>" + item + "</td>" +
     "</tr>");
 });
```

It looked fool, coz, my code create just three row with one column like this

```
+--------------+
|object Object |
|object Object |
|object Object |
+--------------+
```

But, I need three row with 13 column. 
P.S. In my case just 13 column, but in production

Comment: Please add a plunker or js fiddle.

Comment: please share the expected output

Comment: The jQuery code is written for array of objects. And the data is in  the format of object of objects.

Comment: @Fadly was any of the posted answers helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this (haven't tested it):

```
var html = "";
for(var val in item){
   html += "<tr>";
   for(var cols in item[val])
    {
        html += "<td>" + item[val][cols ] + "</td>";
    }
   html += "</tr>";
}
$('#table-review').find('tbody').append(html);
```

**EDIT:** I tested it and it works, please see the below fiddle:

[<kbd>**Check Demo Here**</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/Luthando/h84p27aj/)

Answer (score 1):

The `item` inside of `each` is the the object equal to `response.isi["0"]`. So you need to loop the `item` too, to create the columns. For better understanding I renamed the inner varibales to `row` and `column`.

```js
var response = {};
response.isi = {
"0": {
    "0": "NO",
    "1": "COLUMN1",
    "2": "COLUMN2",
    "3": "COLUMN3",
    "4": "COLUMN4",
    "5": "COLUMN5",
    "6": "COLUMN6",
    "7": "COLUMN7",
    "8": "COLUMN8",
    "9": "COULMN9",
    "10": "COLUMN10",
    "11": "COLUMN11",
    "12": "COLUMN12",
    "13": "COLUMN13"
},
"1": {
    "0": "1",
    "1": "NYK FUJI ",
    "2": "AJU150708 ",
    "3": " ",
    "4": "6C7132 ",
    "5": "977NEF ",
    "6": "JKT-P.T.IRON WORKS ",
    "7": "977NEF ",
    "8": "KCH8ATDM ",
    "9": "17.9",
    "10": "1690",
    "11": "2150",
    "12": "6C7132-1690 ",
    "13": "175"
},
"2": {
    "0": "2",
    "1": "NYK FUJI ",
    "2": "AJU150708 ",
    "3": " ",
    "4": "6C7132 ",
    "5": "977NEF ",
    "6": "JKT-P.T.IRON WORKS ",
    "7": "977NEF ",
    "8": "KCH8ATDM ",
    "9": "17.9",
    "10": "1700",
    "11": "2138",
    "12": "6C7132-1700 ",
    "13": "176"
  }
};

$.each(response.isi, function(r, row) {
    var tr = $('#table-review').find('tbody').append("<tr>");
  
    $.each(row, function(c, column) {
        tr.append("<td>" + column + "</td>");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-review">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're not getting the value of each key inside JSON.

A simple explanation, every JSON object has **keys** and **values**.

```
object {
    key: value,
    key: value,
    key: value
}
```

So you need to iterate inside each object and get each property value. Something like this:

```
for (var col = 0; col < 14; col++) {
  for (var row = 0; row < 14; row++) {
    $('#table-review').find('tbody')
      .append(
       "<tr>" + "<td>" + item[col][row] + "</td>" + "</tr>"
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the generic `tableMaker` can generate you the table HTML. It takes an array of objects. Each object represent a row where object properties are used as headers (if the second argument provided as `true`) and the values are the cells.

In your case we have a utility function called `getTableData` which converts your data into an array of objects to be provided to `tableMaker`.

```js
function tableMaker(o,h){
  var keys = Object.keys(o[0]),
  rowMaker = (a,t) => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p + (i === a.length-1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>"
                                                                  : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"),"<tr>"),
      rows = o.reduce((r,c) => r + rowMaker(keys.reduce((v,k) => v.concat(c[k]),[]),"td"),h ? rowMaker(keys,"th") : []);
  return "<table>" + rows + "</table>";
}

function getTableData(data){
  var ok = Object.keys(data);
  return ok.map(k => data[k]);
} 

var data = {
"0": {
    "0": "NO",
    "1": "COLUMN1",
    "2": "COLUMN2",
    "3": "COLUMN3",
    "4": "COLUMN4",
    "5": "COLUMN5",
    "6": "COLUMN6",
    "7": "COLUMN7",
    "8": "COLUMN8",
    "9": "COULMN9",
    "10": "COLUMN10",
    "11": "COLUMN11",
    "12": "COLUMN12",
    "13": "COLUMN13"
},
"1": {
    "0": "1",
    "1": "NYK FUJI ",
    "2": "AJU150708 ",
    "3": " ",
    "4": "6C7132 ",
    "5": "977NEF ",
    "6": "JKT-P.T.IRON WORKS ",
    "7": "977NEF ",
    "8": "KCH8ATDM ",
    "9": "17.9",
    "10": "1690",
    "11": "2150",
    "12": "6C7132-1690 ",
    "13": "175"
},
"2": {
    "0": "2",
    "1": "NYK FUJI ",
    "2": "AJU150708 ",
    "3": " ",
    "4": "6C7132 ",
    "5": "977NEF ",
    "6": "JKT-P.T.IRON WORKS ",
    "7": "977NEF ",
    "8": "KCH8ATDM ",
    "9": "17.9",
    "10": "1700",
    "11": "2138",
    "12": "6C7132-1700 ",
    "13": "176"
  }
},
tableData = getTableData(data),
tableHTML = tableMaker(tableData,true);
myTable.innerHTML = tableHTML;
```

```html
<div id="myTable"></div>
```